# Manager user accounts with NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, membership, roles, user-accounts, built-in

I'm searching for a functionality in NHibernate to add or remove user accounts of the current database. Is there a built-in function? Or do I have to make it manually for each database?

Thank you very much,
Mark

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a built-in function, as it's outside the scope for NHibernate.